# How do export an invoice or current statement using Acumatica's SOAP API via PHP?

Tags: php, soap, acumatica

How do export an invoice or current statement using Acumatica's SOAP API via PHP?

I can generate SOAP PHP stub classes using https://www.wsdltophp.com/

Most of the examples I have found use .Net

The WSDL my client has provided me with is:
http://erp.triode.co.nz/pmsdb/Soap/INEXPORT.asmx?WSDL

From what I can see, it seems that Acumatica has multiple WSDL's for different procedures. If someone could give me a point in the right direction that would be great. I can authenticate with the Acumatica endpoint, I just get stuck as to where to start with this use case.

***UPDATE****

OK I am using the Acumatica PHP helper files now which are quite helpful but stuck again unfortunately trying to export a list of invoices for one customer:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(-1);

require_once('AcumaticaGate.php');

//$wsdl = "http://erp.triode.co.nz/pmsdb/Soap/AR402000.asmx?WSDL";
// $client = new AcumaticaGate('<user_login>', '<user_password>', '<folder_name>','http://<computer>/<website>');

//Can't provide credentials for security reasons unfortunately
$un = ""
$pw = ""; 

$client = new AcumaticaGate($un, $pw, 'AR402000','http://erp.triode.co.nz/pmsdb');

$customer_id = "DAR";
$doctype = "Invoice";

$selection = $client->Schema->GetSchemaResult->Selection;
$customer = $selection->Customer = $customer_id;
$all_docs = $selection->ShowAllDocuments = true;
$unreleased = $selection->IncludeUnreleasedDocuments = true;
$type_doc = $client->Schema->GetSchemaResult->Documents->TypeDisplayDocType;

// FILTERS
$filters = array();

array_push($filters,
               $client->PrepareSimpleFilter(clone $type_doc, FilterCondition::Equals, $doctype));


$export_param = new Export();
$export_param->commands         = array($customer, $all_docs, $unreleased);
$export_param->filters                   = $filters;
$export_param->breakOnError    = true
$export_param->includeHeaders = false;
$export_param->topCount            = 0;

$export = $client->Client->Export($export_param);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($export);
echo "</pre>";

// echo $client->Client->__getLastRequest();

?>
```

Getting error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at PX.Api.SyImportContext.ParseCommand(SyCommand cmd) at PX.Api.SyExportContext.a(SYMappingField A_0) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at PX.Api.SyExportContext..ctor(SYMapping mapping, IEnumerable`1 fields, String[] providerFields, Dictionary`2 viewFilters, Boolean breakOnError, Int32 start, Int32 count, LinkedSelectorViews selectorViews, String rowFilterField) at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.ExportInternal(String screenId, Command[] commands, Filter[] filters, Int32 startRow, Int32 topCount, Boolean includeHeaders, Boolean breakOnError, PXGraph graph, Boolean bindGuids, Boolean mobile, Boolean isSelector, String forcePrima in /vagrant_www/triode-soap/AR402000/Screen.php on line 549

**This is the .Net method I am trying to reverse engineer:**

*Example 4.3.4: Retrieving the List of Invoices of a Customer
This example, which is provided for reference only, shows how to get the list of invoices for a customer
(by customer ID) on the Customer Details form (AR402000; Finance > Accounts Receivable > Work
Area > Explore).*

```
class CustomerDetail
{
//Retrieving the list of invoices for the customer
//on the Customer Details form (AR402000)
public static void ExportInvoices()
{
    //Input data
    string customerID = "C000000003";
    string docType = "Invoice";
    using
   (
       //Connect to the web services and log in to Acumatica ERP
       Screen context = WebServiceConnector.InitializeWebService()
   )
  {
  try
  {
      //Get the schema of the Customer Details form (AR402000)
      AR402000Content customerDetailSchema = context.AR402000GetSchema();
      //Configure the list of commands
      var commands = new Command[]
      {
          //Select the documents from the inquiry
          new Value
          {
               Value = customerID,
               LinkedCommand = customerDetailSchema.Selection.Customer
          },
          new Value
          {
                Value = "True",
                LinkedCommand =      customerDetailSchema.Selection.ShowAllDocuments
          },
          new Value
         {
                Value = "True",
                LinkedCommand = customerDetailSchema.Selection.IncludeUnreleasedDocuments
         },

         //Get the values of the elements
        customerDetailSchema.Documents.TypeDisplayDocType,
        customerDetailSchema.Documents.ReferenceNbr,
        customerDetailSchema.Documents.Date,
        customerDetailSchema.Documents.Status
};

//Select for export only the orders of the needed customer
var filters = new Filter[]
{
new Filter
{
    Field = customerDetailSchema.Documents.TypeDisplayDocType,
    Condition = FilterCondition.Equals,
    Value = docType
}
};

//Export the records
var custormerInvoices = context.AR402000Export(commands, filters, 0, true, false);

//Save the export results to a CSV file
IOHelper.SaveToCSVFile(custormerInvoices,    string.Format(@"SOInvoices_Customer_{0}.csv", customerID));
}
finally
{
//Log out from Acumatica ERP
context.Logout();
}
}
}
}
```

#### UPDATE

Updated script and now getting an empty response from the API endpoint, at least it is not an error but still stuck unfortunately, so accepts but doesn't return anything:

***NEW CODE***

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(-1);

require_once('AcumaticaGate.php');

//$wsdl = "http://erp.triode.co.nz/pmsdb/Soap/INEXPORT.asmx?WSDL";

// $client = new AcumaticaGate('<user_login>', '<user_password>', '<folder_name>','http://<computer>/<website>');

$un = "";
$pw = "";

$client = new AcumaticaGate($un, $pw, 'AR402000','http://erp.triode.co.nz/pmsdb');

$customer_id = "3678";
$doctype = "Invoice";


$selection = $client->Schema->GetSchemaResult->Selection;
$customer = $selection->Customer;
$all_docs = $selection->ShowAllDocuments;
$unreleased = $selection->IncludeUnreleasedDocuments;
$type_doc = $client->Schema->GetSchemaResult->Documents->TypeDisplayDocType;

$command = array();
array_push($command, $client->PrepareValue($customer_id, $customer));
array_push($command, $client->PrepareValue('true', $all_docs));
array_push($command, $client->PrepareValue('true', $unreleased));


// FILTERS
$filters = array();


array_push($filters, $client->PrepareSimpleFilter(clone $type_doc, FilterCondition::Equals, $doctype));
array_push($filters, $client->PrepareSimpleFilter(clone $customer, FilterCondition::Equals, $customer_id));



$export_param = new Export();
$export_param->commands       = $command;
$export_param->filters        = $filters;
$export_param->breakOnError   = true;
$export_param->includeHeaders = false;
$export_param->topCount       = 0;

$export = $client->Client->Export($export_param);

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($export);
// echo "</pre>";

echo $client->Client->__getLastRequest();

?>
```

#### SOAP XML REQUEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-  ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.acumatica.com/typed/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Export>
        <ns1:commands>
            <ns1:Command xsi:type="ns1:Value">
                <ns1:Value>3678</ns1:Value>
                <ns1:LinkedCommand xsi:type="ns1:Field">
                    <ns1:FieldName>CustomerID</ns1:FieldName>
                    <ns1:ObjectName>Filter</ns1:ObjectName>
                    <ns1:Value>Customer</ns1:Value>
                    <ns1:Commit>true</ns1:Commit>
                </ns1:LinkedCommand>
            </ns1:Command>
            <ns1:Command xsi:type="ns1:Value">
                <ns1:Value>true</ns1:Value>
                <ns1:LinkedCommand xsi:type="ns1:Field">
                    <ns1:FieldName>ShowAllDocs</ns1:FieldName>
                    <ns1:ObjectName>Filter</ns1:ObjectName>
                    <ns1:Value>ShowAllDocuments</ns1:Value>
                    <ns1:Commit>true</ns1:Commit>
                </ns1:LinkedCommand>
            </ns1:Command>
            <ns1:Command xsi:type="ns1:Value">
                <ns1:Value>true</ns1:Value>
                <ns1:LinkedCommand xsi:type="ns1:Field">
                    <ns1:FieldName>IncludeUnreleased</ns1:FieldName>
                    <ns1:ObjectName>Filter</ns1:ObjectName>
                    <ns1:Value>IncludeUnreleasedDocuments</ns1:Value>
                    <ns1:Commit>true</ns1:Commit>
                </ns1:LinkedCommand>
            </ns1:Command>
        </ns1:commands>
        <ns1:filters>
            <ns1:Filter>
                <ns1:Field>
                    <ns1:FieldName>DisplayDocType</ns1:FieldName>
                    <ns1:ObjectName>Documents</ns1:ObjectName>
                    <ns1:Value>TypeDisplayDocType</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Field>
                <ns1:Condition>Equals</ns1:Condition>
                <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Invoice</ns1:Value>
                <ns1:OpenBrackets>0</ns1:OpenBrackets>
                <ns1:CloseBrackets>0</ns1:CloseBrackets>
                <ns1:Operator>And</ns1:Operator>
            </ns1:Filter>
            <ns1:Filter>
                <ns1:Field>
                    <ns1:FieldName>CustomerID</ns1:FieldName>
                    <ns1:ObjectName>Filter</ns1:ObjectName>
                    <ns1:Value>Customer</ns1:Value>
                    <ns1:Commit>true</ns1:Commit>
                </ns1:Field>
                <ns1:Condition>Equals</ns1:Condition>
                <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">3678</ns1:Value>
                <ns1:OpenBrackets>0</ns1:OpenBrackets>
                <ns1:CloseBrackets>0</ns1:CloseBrackets>
                <ns1:Operator>And</ns1:Operator>
            </ns1:Filter>
        </ns1:filters>
        <ns1:topCount>0</ns1:topCount>
        <ns1:includeHeaders>false</ns1:includeHeaders>
        <ns1:breakOnError>true</ns1:breakOnError>
    </ns1:Export>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

#### END POINT RESPONSE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <ExportResponse xmlns="http://www.acumatica.com/typed/">
            <ExportResult />
        </ExportResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the wsdltophp.com author, I strongly advise you to use the new generator version from [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator), it should work better than with the previous version. If not, don't hesitate contacting me via email.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I really do feel that it is better to use Acumatica's PHP tools for this project, as Acumatica is very complex and has multiple WSDls. I have made progress, probably just need some input from someone at Acumatica.

Have tried with .Net following Acumatica's documentation and I get the same result, I will submit my findings here too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever got this to work, but following is an example that I'm able to run that pulls inventory items with "1" in the name.  Hope it's helpful.

```
//Create a Filter with which we'll see if our inventory item is already present
$field = new Field();
$field->FieldName = $schema->StockItemSummary->InventoryID->FieldName;
$field->ObjectName = $schema->StockItemSummary->InventoryID->ObjectName;
$condition = FilterCondition::Contain;
//Search String
$string = "1";
$filter = $client->PrepareSimpleFilter($field,$condition,$string);

//Create an Export command that will contain fields for return, various options, and our filter array
$export = new Export();
$export->commands = array(
    $schema->StockItemSummary->InventoryID,
    $schema->StockItemSummary->Description
);
$export->topCount = 15;
$export->includeHeaders = false;
$export->breakOnError = false;
$export->filters = array(
    $filter
);
```